# How do we compress JSON in back end and decompress in front end?

Tags: json, python-3.x, vue.js

I'm sending large JSON objects between the back end server(flask) to front end (Vue JS) which is around 35MB. Is there a recommended way to compress the JSON on the back-end and de-compress it on the front-end?

Comment: Are you sure that sending 35 MB to \*every client\* is a good idea?

Comment: @Tomalak Yes. When they filter for data, sometimes the count is too big and due to this the size of JSON sent increases.

Comment: Usually only the part of the data is sent to the client that it needs to display *right now*. You can display only a very small portion of 35 MB of data at the same time anyway. When the user scrolls, or shows the next page in a paged table, more data is is loaded via Ajax. Sending all 35 MB at once is bad for client performance *and* server performance, compressing it for transfer will not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While 35MB seems like an extraordinarily large response object, you might use gzip to compress the response.

Since you are using Flask, you might consider looking at the example in this snippet for reference: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/122/